# How do I make Vite not convert process.env to specific value during build?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs, rollup, vite

## Background

I use Vite to build my project from esModule to CommonJS, and I will run the result in NodeJS.

One problem that bothers me is that `process.env` has been converted to a specific value, but I just want `process.env` to stay the way it is because I will pass in the concrete value when NodeJS runs the result.

Although it is built using Vite, I think this should be a problem with Rollup.

**UPDATE**: It should be vite's problem.

## Detail

My code looks something like this:

```
useVariable(process.env.ROOT)
```

The result of the build is something like this:

```
useVariable({}.ROOT)
```

The build result I expect:

```
useVariable(process.env.ROOT) // Keep it as it is
```

It's my config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: '../../dist',
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.ts'),
      name: 'main',
      formats: ['cjs']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        autoExternal({ packagePath: './package.json' })
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is almost certainly [related to vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables). Rollup does nothing to `process.env` on its own.

Comment: There is a workaround, use `process['env']`.